# Set parent div to absolute child div height

Tags: jquery, height, absolute

I have multiple .parent divs each containing an absolute positioned .child div.
I managed to extend the height of .parent to the height of the .child using the following code.

However, this makes every .parent the same height, which is the height of the largest .child in the site.
I need each .parent to only extend it's height to their own .child and no larger.

Any suggestions?

```
function parentHeight(){
     divHeight = $('.parent .child').height();
     $('.parent').css({'height' : divHeight});
 }
 parentHeight();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following using [jQuery.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

```js
function parentHeight(){
    $('.parent .child').each((i,el) => {
      $(el).closest(".parent").css({'height' : $(el).height()})
    });
 }
 parentHeight();
```

```css
.parent {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent"><div class="child" style="height:200px">A</div></div>
<div class="parent"><div class="child" style="height:300px">B</div></div>
<div class="parent"><div class="child" style="height:400px">C</div></div>
```

Comment: @Leanne - Glad to help you